# Craft News Feed not working after 2.5 Update

Tags: control-panel, dashboard-widgets

Not a major thing but I just noticed the Craft News Feed on the dashboard is not showing.  It is still looking for https://craftcms.com/news.rss.  Any ideas what is up with that?

Comment: Can you check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for any feed related error messages?

Comment: I dont see any errors in PHP log

Comment: Same issue is happening on all sites we upgraded.  Both on local and production servers.  Weird

Comment: The widget is there but it is just not getting any values.  Can I send you the craft.log Brad?

Comment: Found issue: 2015/12/02 20:55:56 [warning] [application] There was a problem parsing the feed: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like it's a SSL certificate problem on your box: https://www.google.com/search?q=SSL+certificate+problem%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate

Comment: @BradBell this site is just setup on local DEV environment. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @BradBell is the issue with your SSL for https://craftcms.com or some issue as we are in development mode?

Comment: All traffic to craftcms.com is done over SSL now (including the feed).  The error your getting is saying that the root CA on your box is outdated and your cURL can't validate that it's connecting to craftcms.com over SSL, so you or your host will need to update it.

Comment: I will look to get that updated. Just odd that it is happening in 4 completely different hosting environments.

Comment: Hi Brad.  On another box Craft is showing this in the craft.log: 

"2015/12/03 14:21:55 [warning] [application] There was a problem parsing the feed: cURL error 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'craftcms.com'"

Comment: This worked on my local dev box:

Use this certificate: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Copy this certificate on your disk. And use this on php.ini

curl.cainfo = "path_to_cert\cacert.pem"

Comment: Would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Comment: It fixes the code 60 issue but not the code 51.  STill getting this error and no RSS feed.

2015/12/03 19:27:09 [warning] [application] There was a problem parsing the feed: cURL error 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'craftcms.com'

Comment: Can you check this Brad? Your cert is for *.craftcms.com and you are then trying to use it with http://craftcms.com which is not correct according to wildcard rules in RFC 2818 as it is missing a subdomain. If you want to use it for just plain old craftcms.com without a subdomain, you need to add a Subject Alternative Name in the wildcard.  I am not sure if you have done this, but this may explain it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445934/wildcard-ssl-certificate-generates-error-when-no-subdomain-is-used.

Comment: You guys probably have it correct but I just wanted to have you check as that is what the error 51 means.  No idea why we are still getting that one.

Comment: I see the news feed was change from http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogandtonic to https://craftcms.com/news.rss so that explains why the 2.4 sites are working and not the 2.5 sites.

Comment: I have tried many fixes found online and I still get this error and the News Feed is not displaying:
 
2015/12/03 21:24:08 [warning] [application] There was a problem parsing the feed: cURL error 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'craftcms.com'

Answer (score 1):

Just checked 2 upgraded sites of me and to me it's working..

Comment: I upgraded 6 sites and all 6 show none of the feed. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I will work with support on this directly as it appears to be an issue with our environment.